# How should rabbis answer questions on disputed issues?

Tags: halacha-theory, rabbis, machlokes

You have a halachic question.  Unknown to you, there is a dispute on the matter.  Some rule as (A) and some rule as (B).  You ask your Rav.  He will give you one of three answers:

(1) The answer is (A).

(2) There is a dispute on the matter.  Some rule as (A) and some rule as (B). But I rule as (A) and that's what you must do since you are a member of my community.

(3) There is a dispute on the matter.  Some rule as (A) and some rule as (B). So you can do either one.

Which is the best rabbinical answer?  Or are they halachically equivalent?

Comment: What is the difference between 1 and 2

Comment: (1) doesn't want to burden you and gives you a simple, direct answer, his preferred.  (2) tells you more, but adds that if you want to be a member of his community you must do as he says.  (3) gives you a choice.

Comment: Given the mitzva of talmud torah, the more info the rabbi can sneakingly teach someone the better. But that has nothing to do with his responsibility to answer a halakhic question. That's all I can see different between 1 and 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  Does a Jew need to know about disputes?  And what fraction of rabbis rule one way and what fraction rule the other; and whether one should assign weights to opinions?  En le-davar sof.

Comment: A jew needs to know the whole Torah, including all the disputes. But that's not what you are asking about here

Comment: These aren't all the options.

Comment: Please clarify your question - are you asking: 
(a) whether the Rabbi's opinion matters when there is a dispute; 
(b) whether the Rabbi is obligated/advised to inform that his ruling is actually debatable; or 
(c) when there is a dispute, does the person asking have the rights to choose between two opinions to suit his preference?

Comment: It seems to me the Arukh haShulchan does both 2 & 3, depending on whether how strongly he felt B was inferior. Whereas the Mishnah Berurah does #2. In contrast, the Shulchan Arukh and Rama tend to do 1 & 2. And working back in time, the Rambam only did #2.

Comment: Of course the quick popularist how-to guides like the Qitzur Shulchan Arukh and Chayei Adam do almost entirely #1.

Comment: What do you mean by "best answer"?

Comment: 1. Is it new to you that there's absolutely no systemic approach to Halachic reasoning and Paskening? 2. Your question is impossible to answer as you didn't specify what kind of a dispute is on the matter, who's asking, who's the rabbi, etc. The same rabbi might reply differently on the same matter to different people and even to the same person at different times (depending on the proficiency of the latter).

Answer (score -1):

The best Rabbinical answer would be either be 1 or 2 depending on the knowledge of the questioner. Some people get confused when they hear a multitude of opinions, they only want the final Psak Halacha.
Option number 3 isn't a great option unless he would say normally the Psak is like this but because of extenuating circumstances one can rely on the lenient opinions.

Comment: It honestly depends on the case. You can't declare a "best" answer, as any given answer of the three is the "best" for what it is answering.